# Why is only the first button turning green?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a noobie programmer, using MAC OS and Visual Studio Code trying to build a responsive fitness routine in HTML for personal use, as a personal project.

I am trying to get all my buttons to turn green on click, the first one is turning green fine, but the rest are not. I have uploaded a code pen here: https://codepen.io/3991chris/full/OJEZwKL

Any help would be awesome!

I tried

```
let btnDone = document.querySelectorAll('#done');
```

Comment: Check the docs, [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a collection of DOM elements, not a single one.

Comment: the docs? what would those be? :)

Comment: Now checked your codepen and you use `querySelector`. The problem appears to be repeated use of the same id. An id must not be repeated and `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` will only ever find the first one.

Comment: I tried changing the id's of all buttons and creating new queryselectors, but not luck as well

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I'm assuming you were warned about that when you wrote the question and rudely stuck a single line of code into the question body to hack your way around the check. Don't do that.

Comment: Quentin, I am new at all of this, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There's two main issues in your code. Firstly all the buttons have the same `#done` id applied to them, which is invalid. `id` must be unique within the DOM. Change these to a `class`.

From there you need to amend your JS code to use `querySelectorAll('.done')` so that it returns a collection of all the elements you can loop through. Within that loop you can bind your event handlers to each button.

Secondly, it looks like your goal is to toggle the styling of the buttons on successive clicks. Therefore you should `toggle()` the class on the element, not use `removeClickHandler()`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.done').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.classList.toggle('active'));
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn .done.active {
  background-color: #4cae4c;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="arm day a.html">A</a>
    <a href="leg day b.html">B</a>
    <a href="ab & chest day c.html">C</a>
    <a class="active" href="leg day d.html">D</a>
    <a href="arm day e.html">E</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Leg Day D</h1>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/deadlift.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <h1>1. Deadlift</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back<br> hip stiff</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>60 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/sumosquat.png" style="width:100%">
    <h1>2. SumoSquats</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, wide legs,<br> make sure back straight</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>80 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>85 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/flexora.webp" style="width:100%">
    <h1>3. Flex Chair</h1>
    <p>alig knees with chair, <br> keep back on seat</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/stepups.png" style="width:100%">
    <h1>4. StepUps</h1>
    <p>Use bench or box <br> and do 10 each leg,<br> up and down same leg</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 20</td>
        <td>15 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 20</td>
        <td>20 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 20</td>
        <td>20 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 20</td>
        <td>25 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/adutora.webp" style="width:100%">
    <h1>5. Adutora</h1>
    <p>Stretch to allow wider leg</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>Max kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>Max kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>Max kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>Max kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/pelvicthrust.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <h1>6. Pelvic Thrust</h1>
    <p>Top of shoulders and chest<br>should be on bench</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>80 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>80 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/gemeossentado.webp" style="width:100%">
    <h1>7. Seated Calf Raise</h1>
    <p>Make sure to go slow</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>60 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 10</td>
        <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 10</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/landminesquat.webp" style="width:100%">
    <h1>8. Landmine Squat</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>40 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>45 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>50 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>55 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/pullthrough.webp" style="width:100%">
    <h1>9. Pull Through</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>20 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>30 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>35 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>40 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/liedownlegcurl.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <h1>10. Lie Down Leg Curl</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back</p>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="done">Done</button>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Set X Rep</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>50 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>55 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5 * 8</td>
        <td>60 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4 * 8</td>
        <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! the remove eventlistener didnt work tho :( ill try and figure it out!

Comment: You mean the use of `toggle` on the classList didn't work...?

Comment: I had to add the color green but i updated the codepen, I see what you did with you JS! really useful! https://codepen.io/3991chris/pen/OJEZwKL

Comment: NVM I GOT IT!!! :DDDDD

Answer (score -1):

I add Jquery CDN, and change your javascript.
I hope you understand it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("div div button").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("activeButton");
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.activeButton {
  background-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="card">
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="arm day a.html">A</a>
      <a href="leg day b.html">B</a>
      <a href="ab & chest day c.html">C</a>
      <a class="active" href="leg day d.html">D</a>
      <a href="arm day e.html">E</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h1>Day 1</h1>
    <img src="images/deadlift.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <h1>1. Deadlift</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back<br> hip stiff</p>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="done" class="">Done</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th> <th>Set X Rep</th> <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td> <td>4 * 8</td> <td>60 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td> <td>5 * 8</td> <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td> <td>5 * 8</td> <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td> <td>4 * 8</td> <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h1>Day 2</h1>
    <img src="images/deadlift.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <h1>1. Push Up</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back<br> hip stiff</p>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="done" class="">Done</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th> <th>Set X Rep</th> <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td> <td>4 * 8</td> <td>60 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td> <td>5 * 8</td> <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td> <td>5 * 8</td> <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td> <td>4 * 8</td> <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h1>Day 3</h1>
    <img src="images/deadlift.jpeg" style="width:100%">
    <h1>1. Jump</h1>
    <p>Feet at 45 angle, back straight,<br>shoulders back<br> hip stiff</p>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="done" class="">Done</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Week</th> <th>Set X Rep</th> <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td> <td>4 * 8</td> <td>60 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td> <td>5 * 8</td> <td>65 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td> <td>5 * 8</td> <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td> <td>4 * 8</td> <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: OP use Vanilla JS